# rate of change, water filling tank

Tags: calculus

'A tank is in the form of a cone with the point downward, and the
height and diameter are each 10 feet. How fast is the water pouring in
at the moment when it is 5 feet deep and the surface is rising at the rate
of 4 feet per minute?'

[image: my incorrect solution]

where is my mistake?

Comment: why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: Calculate the water area at that depth and multiply by 4 as a second check.

Comment: I should also say that you made some work for yourself (and increased the chance of error) by leaving the substitution $r=h/2$ so late...

Comment: back of the book says the answer should be 25π/12 ft^3/min = 6.55 ft^3/min.

Comment: I have to second @Joffan with making the volume formula only in terms of $h$ very early on.

Comment: The book answer would be correct if the surface is rising at 4 *inches* per minute. Suggest you check the wording.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right. here is a way you can avoid lots of work and volume formula and all that. At a particular instant, what is important is the surface area. You can forget about that it is cone: it might as well be a cylinder at that instant.

- Let $r$ be the radius at height $h$.
- From the geometry, $r = h/2$.
- You want to find  ${dV \over dt}$ when $h = 5$ and $\frac{dh}{dt} =
     4$.

The change in volume at this instant is

$$dV = \pi *(5/2)^2 dh$$

If you divide both sides by $dt$ you get

$$\begin {align}
{dV \over dt} &= \pi * {25 \over 4} *4 \\
 &= 25 \pi\  ft^3/min \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: back of the book says the answer should be 25π/12 ft^3/min = 6.55 ft^3/min.

Comment: @anatta, i think the answer in the back of the book is wrong if the cone has diameter and height are 10ft as we took. cheek the problem statement again.

Comment: i copied and pasted the problem.

its from a pdf of 'calculus for the practical man'.

was just curious the solutions section would tell me that my answer is off by a factor of 12.

thank you for taking the time to review my work.

Comment: @anatta I **really** suggest that the problem originally said "4 inches per minute". This fits the book answer exactly. Now who made the transcription error, I have no idea.

Comment: @joffan good call. that does make a lot of sense. thanks.

Comment: i think @Joffan is right. it is more "reasonable" for the water to rise at $4/12 ft/min$ than $4 ft/min.$

Comment: @Joffan: Nice, thinking outside the cone.